# How to enable auth_basic only for POST requests in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, http-authentication

I am getting the following error message in Nginx :

> "satisfy" directive is not allowed here

Here is my nginx config for basic HTTP authentication :

```
location / {

                   limit_except GET {
                      satisfy any;

                      allow  some_address;
                      allow  another_address;
                      deny  all;


                      auth_basic "Elasticsearch Authentication";
                      auth_basic_user_file some_file;
                   }

    }
```

This configuration is inspired from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/128538/nginx-basic-auth-only-for-post) and [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#limit_except). Can you help me solve this problem ?

Comment: Put `satisfy` outside of `limit_except`

Comment: It worked ! thanks